# Installing Ubuntu on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have partitioned my drive and now I want to install ubuntu into my drive c:. Would it erase my files in drive D:?

I was currently running windows 10

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a installation in Ubuntu you will be prompted with the installation location that you want for the OS, make sure that the disk that you select in that step is the one you have for Ubuntu.

As always i recommend you to make a full backup of all your important files before doing any installation of any new OS on your system.

I hope i have helped you, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are installing Ubuntu in your C: drive, it should not affect your D: drive in any way. While installing Ubuntu, you would be prompted to choosing the location of Installation. At that time, you have to select the C: drive partition and not the D: drive one or else it will format the D: drive instead.
Hope this helps!
Have a nice day!!